# Call a modal (Bootstrap 5) from Jinja2 templating

Tags: flask, jinja2, bootstrap-modal

I'm likely the nth person to have asked this question but am having trouble parsing the relevant documentation; I want to add a modal dialogue to a button declared with a function in Jinja2.

The code for the form where I want the modal to be called is below - the modal should be called when the shutdown button (last line) is pressed, to confirm this action.

```
 <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form" 
 style="text-align: center;">
    {{ power_form.hidden_tag() }}
                
    {% if power_status == "None" %}
       {{ power_form.power_on(class_="btn btn-default") }}
       {{ power_form.power_cycle(class_="btn btn-default") }}
       {{ power_form.power_off(class_="btn btn-default") }}
```

The modal dialogue is called 'Shutdown Confirmation' and has been declared later. I am unsure how to call it as online examples show the button declaration is used instead of the {{. Here is the bootstrap documentation for this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs- 
toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
   Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap 5 you can activate the modal panel by data attributes or JS API. I assume you want to use the data-attribute method.

With WTForms you can pass any attribute to the rendered element, just replace any dash with underscore (because Python syntax), and WTForms will change them back to dashes:

```
{{ power_form.power_off(type="button", class_="btn btn-default", data_bs_toggle="modal" data_bs_target="#exampleModal") }}
```

Change the `#exampleModal` to the corresponding selector of your modal element. We also change the type of the button from the default `submit` to simple `button`, so it wont submit the form, just open the modal window.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the syntax I was looking for! I am mostly a C/C++ programmer so not very familiar with this form of the data attribute model. Unfortunately the modal window isn't popping up but I think that's likely a separate beast. Thanks, H.